# How to call a variable combined from 2 strings

Tags: php, smarty

I have this:

```
string {$one} = "$hello_"
string {$two} = "world"
```

How can I call the variable `$hello_world` from the above two string variables?
`capture` did not work for me.

Uses Smarty v2.5

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl):

```
{$foo_{$x}}  // will output the variable $foo_1 if $x has a value of 1.
```

So, you want:

```
{${$one}{$two}}
```

---

Since this functionality isn't allowed, I would recommend using a [smarty plugin](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.functions.tpl) to mimic the behavior you want. Template plugins are just simple php functions, called via the [`$smarty->loadPlugin()`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.writing.tpl) method.

Answer (score 1):

{${$foo}{$bar}} will only work in Smarty3, though. In Smarty2 you'd have to write a plugin for that (or simply search the smarty forum, as there are plenty of solutions there…)

Comment: can you suggest search string

Comment: Have a look at this plugin: http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=VarVar - even works with arrays and is easy to identify (search and replace) once you upgrade to Smarty3.

Answer (score 0):

Smarty 2.x doesn't support variable variables.

Variables in smarty are actually stored inside the smarty object so you'd need explicit support in Smarty to use the convenient standard variable-variable syntax.

The following is the best I could come up with in Smarty 2.x.  It uses a PHP block to store the value of the combined result for you.

```
{assign var="one" value="hello_"}
{assign var="two" value="world"}
{assign var="hello_world" value="HELLO!"}

{php}
    $varname = $this->get_template_vars('one').$this->get_template_vars('two');
    $this->assign('result', $this->get_template_vars($varname));
{/php}

{$result}
```

As mentioned, however, you have to get rid of the `$` at the beginning of the value of `$one`.  Otherwise you will need to modify it to the following line:

```
$varname = substr($this->get_template_vars('one'),1).$this->get_template_vars('two');
```

Comment: I would *highly* recommend against this. Using smarty `php` blocks is almost always discouraged, particularly with this example where the block isn't even portable (i.e., it's only good for the particular variable variable being discussed). Use a [plugin](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.functions.tpl) if necessary. I would attempt to solve this from the back-end, trying to mitigate the need for variable variables from the get-go.

Comment: Good effort and working solution, but -1 I'm afraid for the reason eykanal explained: it's the _wrong_ solution.

Comment: @Tomalak - I agree. I wouldn't even use variable variables - but it's what the OP asked.  I think it's silly to -1 a solution because the question was weird.  I wouldn't even recommend using a plugin because that would imply that such a practice is worth supporting.

Comment: I'll admit I'm torn. But I'm still leaning towards the "this is harmful" side. I mean, you don't even write in the answer that it would be an incredibly bad practice to follow the advice you've given.

Comment: @Tomalak Well, maybe we disagree then.  I don't think it's bad advice.  I think it's ugly, but it does the job that was asked.  We simply don't have enough context to even make other suggestions.  I normally would make other suggestions if there was any other suggestion to make (as I said above, a plugin is no substitute, because anything but a hack here implies storing variable names in variables is OK, and I don't think it is OK).